# jms connection factory javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance

Tags: spring, tomcat, ibm-mq, jndi

Hi I am trying to connect WebSphere IBM MQ 7.5.0.7 Connection factory from Tomcat 8. While starting  tomcat server we load spring XML, from that we connect to IBM MQ Connection factory.

Below is the code in spring xml.

```
<bean name="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/JMS/QFX_PF1UATMQCF" />
        </bean>
```

Below code in Context.xml in Tomcat.

```
<Resource name="JMS/QFX_PF1UATMQCF"
        auth="Container"
        type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
        factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
        description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
        HOST="some hostname"
        PORT="1425"
        CHAN="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"
        TRAN="1"
        QMGR="EUQFXP7A"/>
```

Below is the exception i am getting while starting tomcat.

```
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jmsConnectionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy at least the following JAR files to Tomcat (e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`):

- [jms.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1/javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar)
- [com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/ibm/mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.0.4.0/com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar)

As @JoshMc mentioned, you should not use MQ 7.5 anymore.

When starting Tomcat, you may see `WARNING` messages in `catalina.log` like this:

```
24-Feb-2018 22:06:40.473 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to scan [file:.../lib/jms.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../lib/jms.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
```

You can eliminate these warnings by adding the MQ jar to `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` property in `catalina.properties`.

Comment: Few points.  1. at MQ v7.5 IBM does not support copying the jar files from the default locations as you are recommending.  This may work but would be a support issue if you needed to open a ticket with IBM.  2. v7.5 goes out of support at the end of April.  3. v8 and v9 both let you "relocate" the jar files to any location you like in your own organization, they also have Java-All packages which contain only the jar files, in this way it is not required to install a full MQ client any longer if all you need are the jar files for the IBM MQ Classes for Java and IBM MQ Classes for JMS APIs.

Comment: @JoshMc is right: You should not work with MQ 7.5 anymore and you should use the relocatable jar. I will edit my answer.